# White-space in div after elements in overlap position

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have two images in four different divs (eight images total). Each of these image pairs are overlapping in a different way, both vertically and laterally.

The issue is the containing div still renders to the height of both images.

For example: I have two divs that are 400px in height, the second has `top: -200px` on it. Meaning my total height is 600px, but the div still renders to be 800px. Why? And what can we do to eliminate this space?

HTML/RAILS:

```
<div class="feed-images">
    <%= image_tag 'texture-1.jpg', class: 'feed-texture texture-1' %>
    <%= image_tag 'feed-1.jpg', class: 'feed-image feed-1' %>
</div><!-- ".feed-images" -->   

<div class="feed-images">
    <%= image_tag 'texture-2.jpg', class: 'feed-texture texture-2' %>
    <%= image_tag 'feed-2.jpg', class: 'feed-image feed-2' %>
</div><!-- ".feed-images" -->
```

CSS/SASS:

```
.feed-images
  width: 100%
  overflow: hidden

.feed-texture
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  z-index: 10

.feed-image
  position: relative
  z-index: 15
  width: 100%

.feed-1
  top: -200px
  left: 40px

.feed-2
  top: -200px
  left: 80px
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do your `.feed` classes need `position:absolute;`? and a position on your div's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `margin-top` instead of `top`, it works on me

```
margin-top: -200px
```

***top:*** behavior can differ depending on the type of position, `absolute, relative or fixed.`

***margin-top:*** is for measuring the external distance to the element, in relation to the previous one.